# Android app using iOS SDK in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to create small android app in unity. I am using iOS machine. Can i create an android app using iOS sdk in Unity 3d ?

Comment: Are you for real? Of course no.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an actual question? Of course you cannot!